# For $k$ and $l$ real constants, prove: (a) If $l \geq k+1$, $\int^\infty_0$ $e^{-x \frac{sin^k(x)}{x^l}}$ = +$\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

For $k$ and $l$ real constants, prove:

(a) If $l \geq k+1$,   $\int^\infty_0$ $e^{-x \frac{\sin^k(x)}{x^l}}$ = +$\infty$

(b) If $l \geq 1$,   $\int^\infty_0$ $e^{-x \frac{\cos^k(x)}{x^l}}$ = +$\infty$

I am really confused. A gentle nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. For context the current section talks about Fresnel Integrals and the conditions needed in order to be able to switch the order of integration in a double integral. I don't see how either applies to this.

Comment: If $k \in \mathbb{R}$, the quantity $\sin^k x$ is not defined, in general.